# I want to signup and login using facebook in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, asp.net-identity

I want to add a sign up and login button to my mvc application. The application is using asp.net Identity.

Comment: There should be some tutorials out there on the web that can show you how to do this.  If you try it and get stuck, come back with a new question and add the code you tried and a link to the tutorial, and we should be able to help.

Comment: I got the tutorials about the login, but I also want to signup via facebook

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, let us know if we can be of any help.  Welcome to stack  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Facebook should be able to help.  They know more about their code than we do.  Let's see.  Yes, they do have pages for developers.  It may be in JavaScript and .php, but you should be able to understand enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

authentication easily login to your site using Facebook, Twitter, Google or Microsoft

http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/08/facebook-twitter-oauth-openid-login-with-aspnet-mvc-4-application.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1b9079/using-facebook-authentication-in-Asp-Net-mvc/